# ColorDataFunctions applied to Tables of Graphics?

Tags: graphics, color

I'm trying to make a graphic according to a `List`, `n`. `n` has integer values that go from `0` to `Length[n] - 1`, and they are in an arbitrary order. I'm trying to make a horizontal line of `Disk`s that are colored in a sort of gradient that goes from `0` to `n`- like, if we mapped the `Rainbow` gradient onto list `n` of length `7`, `n[x] = 0` would be red, `n[x] = 1` could be yellow, `2` orange and so on. My code so far is below.

```
Graphics[Table[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, Length[n] - 1}}][n[x]], 
   Disk[{2 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, Length[n], 1}]]
```

`n` is defined as a list, but I think I'm calling the `ColorDataFunction` from `ColorData` wrong. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use color gradients to color a discrete set of objects, you can use the built-in rescaling feature of `ColorData[]`. For instance, if you want to color 5 disks, you'll want to use `ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, 5}}]` as the color function, and this should now produce a color for any argument in $[1,5]$.

As an example of this:

```
tl = {3, 4, 2, 5, 1}; n = Length[tl];
cf = ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, n}}];
Graphics[Table[{cf[tl[[k]]], Disk[{2 k, 0}, 1]}, {k, 1, n}]]
```

[image: some colored disks]

But, why not use an *indexed* color scheme instead, which is often more suitable for this particular application?

```
cf = ColorData[61];
Graphics[Table[{cf[tl[[k]]], Disk[{2 k, 0}, 1]}, {k, 1, n}]]
```

[image: more colored disks]

Comment: So what I didn't share was, I'm using this to debug a code golf program with a weird broken sort scheme. :P I didn't see any indexed color schemes that really fit the smooth gradient I was looking for, because I was using these to pinpoint irregularities in a list of numbers that should have been counting up steadily but had some things swapped. I also needed a LOT of distinct colors, because the length of n can go up above 100 for some cases, and I didn't see a lot of indexed color schemes with a lot of indices. Thanks so much for your great solution either way!

Comment: "a LOT of distinct colors" - one might be able to join two or more indexed schemes for the purpose.

Comment: @laudiacay Probably [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3682/946) can help you.

Comment: @Alexey, that's a nice thread; thanks for linking to it!